# Presenting binomial glmer with both continuous and binary factor variables

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, regression-coefficients, presentation

I have binomial outcome data with predictors that are binary factors (presence/absence) and predictors that are continuous variables. I know to scale continuous variables, but what is proper way to present the continuous variable effects beyond saying that, for every standard deviation of the variable, the log-odds ratio changes by the coefficient value? How would I likewise present that as "for every 1000 dollars income away from mean" instead of "for every standard deviation of income"? I could just report the sd values, but it's not as intuitive as "round" figures.

Comment: Could you give an example of your data and the glmer output you are talking about? Is the problem about the fact that you have scalled your variables and run glmer on such data but you want to interpret the results on non-scalled scale? If so, then why did you scale your data in the first place?

Comment: Because if I don't scale the continous data lme4 says that something is too large and the model couldn't be properly identified. When I scale the continuous data, there isn't such a problem.

Comment: By "scaling", do you mean mean centering + standardisation? or do you mean dividing your predictor by some arbitrary value? In the 2nd case, it should make no difference for lme4.

Comment: In this case, I mean centering plus division by sd. Without doing so, I get warnings about the Hessian and model not being identifiable.